# Android SimpleAdapter: Сохранение изменённого состояния контрола

Tags: android, listview

Первый раз использую **SimpleAdapter**, ранее использовал исключительно *ArrayAdapter*, поэтому данного вопроса не возникало (всё делал ручками): как заставить адаптер изменять наборы данных выводимые с помощью SimpleAdapter? Например я использую в адаптере CheckBox (для вывода значений типа boolean), изменяю его состояние, а при перемотке списка данные восстанавливаются исходные.

Comment: Не хватает контекста. Покажите минимум кода который не работает так, как вы хотите.

Comment: Нужно сохранять текущие установки чекбоксов в адаптере в какой то массив и потом восстанавливать из этого массива при создании айтема или использовать режим choice_mode_multiple для списка

Comment: так же само, *ручками*, как и в `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: Госпади, вопросы про затыки с адаптерами не умрут никогда

Comment: Какой тогда смысл в SimpleAdapter если я могу использовать ArrayAdapter?

Comment: @gc986 Лично я в большей степени не вижу смысла вообще юзать любые адаптеры кроме BaseAdapter и SimpleCursorAdapter, ну и новый RecyclerViewAdapter конечно же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаёте глобальный массив **boolean status_array[МНОГО]**, который будет хранить состояние **checkbox-ов**, далее кодим в методе **getView()**, в нём необходимо после создания **CheckBox** устанавливать значение методом `CheckBox.setChecked(status_array[position]);`
Также не забудьте в этом методе добавить слушателя к CheckBox, в котором вы будете получать состояние и добавлять его в **status_array**

Comment: Тогда получается что смысла в SimpleAdapter нет никакого, тоже самое я могу сделать и в ArrayAdapter

Comment: @gc986 Обратите внимание, что ArrayAdapter в отличии от SimpleAdapter является дженериком, т.е. имеет на вход динамический тип данных **ArrayAdapter<T>** vs **SimpleAdapter**. Также у ArrayAdapter есть метод, который позволяет динамически добавлять элементы в адаптере без вызова метода обновления информации. Но в большей степени особой разницы нету. Вот ссылки: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Comment: Спасибо! Вопрос исчерпан.